# Friends list on Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So far on my firebase I have something like:

```
Users
   293840ajldkjfas0d9
       username: Jill
   09283049802930laks
       username: Jack
```

I'm basically going to just have a text field and when someone hits the "add" button, a search through firebase gets done to make sure that username exists, and go from there on connecting the two as friends.

My question is I'm not understanding how I would sort through my data if it's structured like this? I might be totally missing something but is there a way to search through what I have now and say "Go to my users reference, go to through each UID and pull out the username and see if it matches what the user put in the text field, and if so grab the UID connected to the username"?

I'm almost thinking I need to have an entirely separate branch? that I have in addition to what I already have that looks like

```
Usernames
   Jack
       09283049802930laks
   Jill
       lasdjf9j09u90320j09
```

Which would then allow me to just go to my usernames and go through and check through the values inside that (jack/Jill) and then if it exists then pull that uid out of the username.

1) Do I need both of these branches or is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with just my first?

2) How exactly do I check for that match? Would a query be used or just checking for Null somehow?

3) Is this even the right way to go about doing this? I've found little to no information on friends lists online so this is just all an assumption.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the below structure, you can check if a user exists with a single query. Here's all the code you need:

This is the db structure:

```
Users
293840ajldkjfas0d9
   username: Jill
09283049802930laks
   username: Jack
```

Here is the code:

```
    var usernameEntered = self.usernameField.text!

    var databaseReferenceQuery = self.ref.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(usernameEntered).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {



            // No user :(



        } else {

           // User exists! Do stuff!


        }


        }, withCancelBlock: { (error) in

           // An error occurred
    })
```

Once you have established a user exists, I can think of a few ways to go about getting the uid. The key is to find a place where both the uid and the username are stored.

Option 1:

> Create another branch in the users db structure that stores the uid.
>   Set up this branch when the user is signed up.

Option 2:

> Store the username as the displayName in the standard auth system and get the uid from there.
>   Set this up when the user signs up.

That's up to you.

> Response to comments:
>   You can simply retrieve the key of the user in the table, however this will **not** allow access to any auth features and will not allow user accounts to be edited in any way.
>    Examples of situations where this can be useful include updating user info, deleting accounts etc.

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed it to. "queryOrderedByChild" is what I wasn't finding. Thank you!

One last little bit. So if I put in Jill to the searchbar, I can return the Snap which will give me the uid and the username / other information associated with that uid. How do I capture that uid in a variable? So like I type in Jill, it finds the UID that has that username, how do I get Jill's userid from this?

Comment: @Swiftaccnt So you would like to get the UID of the user after establishing he/she exists?

Comment: Yeah. Because I need to check if that user exists by searching via username, and then make them friends by connecting their UIDs. So now that you've established that a friend exists, now I need the UID for that user with that username

Comment: I will add it to the answer @Swiftaccnt

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate all the time and help :)

Comment: Happy to help @Swiftaccnt . Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Swiftaccnt There is no need for creating another branch on the database to get the uid as @GJZ is saying. Just go with `snapshot.key` on your `queryOrderedByChild` and you will have what you want. :)

Comment: @adolfosrs I was definitely hoping that was the case haha, but when I tried that with the current way the database is laid out which you can see up above with the main "users" and then under that a unique id and then under that the username, print snapshot.key I get "users" returned to the console. Its giving me the highest layer, and I need one under that. Any ideas? 

So basically instead of giving me the 20938alkjsdlkfj3 right under the "users" layer, it's just giving me the overarching "user".

Comment: @adolfosrs That will not get you the uid, but rather the user key in that table. There is a difference. The uid allows access to the user in the auth section of Firebase, which is stored separately to the database. The key is only a key to the database element. If you only need an individual key, it might work, but if you plan on accessing the account, the uid is the way to go.

Comment: I added this to the answer @Swiftaccnt